# JS function: Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS function that replaces a parent Node with a Youtube iFrame:

```
function labnolIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.parentNode.dataset.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&controls=1&showinfo=0");
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "youtube-iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    iframe.setAttribute("allowFullscreen", "1");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
```

I dynamically create divs on page load that have an onclick attribute that runs the above function:

```
(function() {
    var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
    for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
        var p = document.createElement("div");
        p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
        p.onclick = labnolIframe;
        v[n].appendChild(p);
    }
})();
```

So far, so good. But I am trying to add an additional icon that calls the function labnolIframe and having difficulty:

```
$('.play-icon').click(function(){
   labnolIframe();
});
```

When I click on .play-icon, I want to run the code that replaces the parent div with the youtube Iframe. But I've discovered that "this" in the above function is not referring to the "this" element in the DOM (unlike when I call it in the first example).

How can I change my code so that it refers to "this" in the last example?

Comment: Pls advise the relationship in the DOM between `.play-icon` elements and the iframe elements?

Comment: Your title contains "Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined". Add some html markup so we can be able to discover elements with classes `youtube-player` and `play-icon`

Comment: 'this' in your javascript function 'labnolIframe' would refer to the document object ( DOM ). If you wish to pass '.play-icon' object to  'labnolIframe', you have to pass it as a parameter or a variable.  $('.play-icon').click(function(){
   labnolIframe(this);
});

Answer (score 0):

To have the click function invoked on `.play-icon` elements use the value of their parent nodes for `this` in calls to the replacement function, you can use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method to specify the `this` value required.  If I have it correctly this is the parent node:

```
$('.play-icon').click(function(){
   labnolIframe.call( this.parentNode); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access `this` object from `.play-icon` , you need to invoke the function `labnolIframe` directly on the `click` event , rather than invoking it inside the `click` event.

Change :

```
$('.play-icon').click(function(){
   labnolIframe();
});
```

to :

```
$('.play-icon').click(labnolIframe);
```

Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/d36k2L3c/7/